# Discrete Wavelet Transform Return Large Values

Tags: matlab

When I implementing the 2D-DWT on a gray image the LL part is returning me a max value that is larger than 255 ,, why is that happen ?? help please

Comment: It is hard to tell why without any information.  However, I could speculate that you may need to scale (and possibly offset) your results, if you want to fit them into a range of [0..255].

Answer (score 0):

It not only larger 255, it also has floating point and should be stored in float or double data type. 
For example, using Haar's wavelet (`( 0.7071    0.7071 )` low-pass filter coeffs) on white image (filled with 255) we get filled with `(0.7071*255*2)*0.7071*2=509.9902` LL subband